Does correcting a density matrix to be positive semi-definite affect its concurrence?
I am working on calculating the concurrence of a two-qubit system, and I encountered an issue where my density matrix occasionally has small negative eigenvalues due to numerical errors in my computations (e.g., constructing the density matrix from Green's functions). To address this, I applied an algorithm to make the matrix positive semi-definite, such as eigenvalue clipping or spectral decomposition followed by normalization.
However, after this correction, the concurrence of the density matrix changes significantly. In some cases, it decreases, and in others, it drops to zero.
My questions are:

How does correcting a density matrix to make it positive semi-definite impact the calculation of concurrence?
Is there a "best practice" for handling small negative eigenvalues while preserving the entanglement properties of the system?
Are there any specific techniques to ensure that the corrected density matrix remains as close as possible to the original physical state?


What is the difference between "decrease" and "drop to zero"?

I would guess that the $\sqrt{\rho}$ is causing issues when $\rho$ is not PSD, but $\rho + \epsilon I > 0$, for a small positive $\epsilon$. The $\sqrt{}$ can be sensitive to $\epsilon$ here, sort of like how $\sqrt{x}$ has a slope discontinuity around $0$.

the issue is in trying to do linear tomography (which you presumably are if you get negative eigenvalues in the reconstruction) and trying to apply the result of that estimate to compute a nonlinear quantity based on eigenvalues. A better approach would be to directly use an estimator for that quantity. For example, using MLE tomography is at least guaranteed to result in an MLE estimator for the concurrence (because a function of an MLE estimator is the MLE estimator of the function)
